# How to order Doxygen groups

Tags: pdf-generation, doxygen

Is it possible to order the groups (i.e. Modules) listing in Doxygen PDF output?
For example if I build my current C project, the group for `commands` is listed in the resulting PDF before `status` as it follows a alphabetical ordering by default whereas I would like `status` to be listed before `commands`.

I tried changing the group name and leaving the tag name the same for the module title, but this did not seem to have any effect, e.g.

```
/** @defgroup g1 Status */   =   /** @defgroup status Status */
```

Thanks

Comment: Typically i handle 'ordering' problems in Doxygen by fiddling with the file order in the INPUT command - listing individual files in the order I want things listed in the document.  However, groups should be file-agnostic so I don't know if that will help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @Cheeseminer's advice here and fiddled with the settings so that only group documentation is shown, then added the files only individually via the INPUT command, listing them in the order I would like.

Downside is that every time I add a new file to my code-base I have to remember to add it to the INPUT command :\

Answer (score 3):

You can set your group order in a block of @defgroup at the first of the code page or befor the first group definition. You don't need a group scope for the defgroup part.

```
/**
* @defgroup A_group Group of Macro A
* @defgroup B_group Group of Macro B
* @defgroup C_group Group of Functions
*/
```

Than define each group with @ingroup in order your code is needed.

```
/**
* @ingoup b_group
* @{
*/
... 
/** @} */
...
/**
* @ingroup a_group
* @{
*/
...
/** @} */
...
/**
* @ingroup c_group
* @{
*/
...
/** @} */
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about pdf output, but for html output it was SORT_GROUP_NAMES = YES in the doxygen config file which solved the issue for me.

https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_sort_group_names

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file that has the groups in the order you want, then put that first in the input line along with . so:

file index.c:

```
/** @addtogroup status
    @addtogroup commands
*/
```

and in the INPUT var in .doxygen

```
INPUT = index.c .
```

This will sort the items as you want, but not add any new symbols, and you can still use the default gathering of source files without worrying about order.